# What is known about space and time complexity of division and base change?

Tags: computational-complexity

The paper [ON THE RAPID COMPUTATION OF VARIOUS POLYLOGARITHMIC CONSTANTS](http://www.davidhbailey.com/dhbpapers/digits.pdf) by Bailey, Borwein, and Plouffe  gives sophisticated calculations which I will not summarize.  But they remark

> We are interested in computing in polynomially logarithmic space and
>   polynomial time. This class is usually denoted SC (space = logO(1)(d)
>   and time = dO(1) where d is the place of the “digit” to be computed).
>   ... It is not known whether division is possible in SC, similarly it is
>   not known whether base change is possible in SC.

I suppose good bounds are known for space and time complexity of division and base change.  What is known about them?

Comment: See also: http://www.cs.nyu.edu/exact/doc/pi-log.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The paper is outdated. Division was proved to be computable in logarithmic space (and a fortiori SC) by Chiu, Davida, and Litow [1]. In fact, they proved it to be in logspace-uniform $\mathrm{NC^1}$; this was improved by Hesse, Allender, and Barrington [2], who proved it is in fully uniform $\mathrm{TC^0}$. The same results also hold for base conversion.

[1] Andrew Chiu, George Davida and Bruce Litow: *Division in logspace-uniform $\mathit{NC}^1$*, RAIRO – Theoretical Informatics and Applications 35 (2001), no. 3, pp. 259–275, doi: [10.1051/ita:2001119](https://doi.org/10.1051/ita:2001119).

[2] William Hesse, Eric Allender, David A. Mix Barrington: *Uniform constant-depth threshold circuits for division and iterated multiplication*, Journal of Computer and System Sciences 65 (2002), no. 4, pp. 695–716, doi: [10.1016/S0022-0000(02)00025-9](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-0000(02)00025-9).